# Unable to import Firebase into Swift Playground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

hope this finds you well.

For the past few painful hours, I've been trying to find a way to import the Firebase module into my Swift Playground, inside of my workspace, *FooWorkspace*. I've tried the following before subsequently importing Firebase in my Playground:

1. Leaving the Playground in *FooWorkspace*, outside of both my projects *FooProject* and *Pod*, as shown [here](https://learnappmaking.com/cocoapods-playground-how-to/).
2. Creating a Framework *FooFramework* and indicating in my Podfile to allocate the Firebase pods into *FooFramework*, and then importing *FooFramework* in my Playground, like in [this](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/playground-driven-development-in-swift-cf167489fe7b).
3. Leaving my Playground inside my *FooProject* instead.

However, all these did not work one bit. I am currently using cocoapods-1.8.4 and XCode Version 11.1 (11A1027).

There were a few points that i am unsure of as well.

1. I was able to import FirebaseCore, but auto-completion in the Playground wasn't working and I couldn't code normally like in my projects.
2. When I created a framework, the option given wasn't a Cocoa-touch Framework, but rather just Framework.

I am truly a novice at iOS development, and know no one in real-life to discuss this, so i feel like i've been going around in circles the past day. Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

**EDITS:**
After some helpful advice from @ryanwils, i restarted my XCode completely and was then able to import FirebaseCore/FirebaseFirestore. However, calling any function from Firebase produced an error. For example, when i called `Firestore.firestore()`, it gave me an error of

`Couldn't lookup symbols:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp`

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've googled around and some threads have mentioned that it is unable to see my pods/classes, but if i am actually able to import Firebase into my playground, shouldn't it be able to see my pods already? Thanks!

Comment: Is there specific reason why you want/need a Playground? Otherwise I would just create iOS app to avoid the hassle connected to Playgrounds..

Comment: I mainly would want to test out my understanding of FireStore queries efficiently, as compared to always running the simulation (if that is what you are saying)

Comment: You mean simulator? Well if you have iOS playground I would bet there is simulator behind the scenes.

Comment: I followed similar instructions above and was able to get it working. At first, autocomplete wasn't working for me either but this happens all the time to me in Playgrounds, even UIKit APIs wouldn't auto-complete. I restarted Xcode and all of a sudden it came back. Can you give that a go?

It's also worth noting you'll likely need to have `import PlaygroundSupport` and `PlaygroundPage.current.setNeedsIndefiniteExecution = true` in order to make sure the network callbacks have enough time to return from Firestore.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ryanwils! After completely restarting my XCode i've been able to import FirebaseCore/FirebaseFirestore without issue. However, after trying to call something like Firestore.firestore(), it gives me an error of :error: `Couldn't lookup symbols:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp`. I've edited my question to reflect this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Breaking out from a comment to an answer)

I was able to get around this in two ways. The first thing may be enough, but if not the second should do it.

1. Compile the workspace. Although the Pods are in the project, the frameworks don't fully exist yet. Compiling may be enough to trigger things.

If that doesn't work...

2. As you mentioned originally in your question, create a new Framework and add `Firebase/Firestore` as a dependency. My Podfile ended up looking like:

```
target 'FirebasePlaygroundDemo' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end

target 'FirebaseDummy' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end
```

where `FirebaseDummy` was the name of my newly created Framework. Then, in the Playground I had to `import FirebaseDummy` **as well as**  `FirebaseCore` and `FirebaseFirestore`.

Hope that helps, can assist further if not!

Comment: Thanks alot once again! I'm so sorry, but i don't exactly know what you mean by building a workspace, relative to building the project (unless you mean that). I've googled around and i could only find instructions for building the project itself,

Comment: I have tried the method of adding a framework. However, it has led to a new error of `error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
`. I have 0 clue what to do from this now, since there is no debug area for the playgrounds. A point to note is that when i added the framework, i did not embed in the application as advised by articles i have seen. Thanks alot!

Comment: Apologies for the delay - that could actually be Firebase throwing an exception. Did you use a manual `FirebaseOptions` instance and call `FirebaseApp.configure(with: customOptions)` or just try `FirebaseApp.configure()`? If the latter, it's likely trying to find a plist but can't so it throws an exception. Normally you'd get to see the exception but it's not running under expected circumstances.

Comment: with your help, I've finally solved the problem in my project and posted it below. Thanks so so much and happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

With immense gratitude to @ryanwils, I've finally found out how to successfully run the Firebase code in a playground. We do need to create an additional framework for this to work.

These are the steps I've taken to successfully do run code on the playground:

1. Set up your workspace so that the Playground file is on the same level as your `xcodeproj` files.
2. As per @ryanwils instructions, create a new framework and in your Podfile specify the required pods for the new framework. I've named mine `PlaygroundFramework`, as you'll see in the code later below.
3. Under the resources folder of your Playground file, copy in your `GoogleService-Info.plist`, like in the photo shown below:
   [image]
4. Use the following code in your Playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import PlaygroundFramework // Your new framework name here
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseFirestore
// ... other modules you need. Remember to build first!

let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")!
let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: filePath)
FirebaseApp.configure(options: options!)

// Your Firebase queries will work here now!
```

The steps above allowed me to run code from various pods in my podfile as well. Hope it works for whoever needs it, and thanks once again to @ryanwils!