# Unable to run Firestore code in Xcode Playground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am hoping to be able to import the FirebaseFirestore module into my Playground in my project (Playground is at the top level, outside of my main and pod project, but within the same workspace). After struggling to even import the module yesterday, I finally discovered that the cure was a simple restart of Xcode with the help of another member :)

However, I've met yet another issue of `error: Couldnt lookup symbols` when trying to do something like `let a = Firestore.firestore()` in the playground. Do note that firebase is working fine in my project. I've installed my Firebase pods through cocoapods as well, and I am currently using cocoapods-1.8.4 and Xcode Version 11.1 (11A1027).

This is my code in my playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import FirebaseFirestore

let a = Firestore.firestore()
```

Also, just out of curiosity, how does Firebase recognize your app? Is it the case that during runtime, the API uses the google *.plist* file to ascertain your identity?

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text on Stack Overflow.  I suggest editing the question and copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: @DougStevenson i've removed it, thanks!

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59397942/unable-to-import-firebase-into-swift-playground